# Functional series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \sin (b_n x)$ is differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

How to prove this conclusion?
$$a_n,b_n\geq0,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n ＜\infty$$
And if functional series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \sin (b_n x)$$ is differentiable for any $x\in \textbf{R}$, then $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n＜\infty$$And I have known that it may be solved by differentiating it term by term and get values on x=0 of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n\cos(b_nx)$,but I'm doubted how to prove that the order of differentiation and summation could be exchangeable,i.e. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n\cos(b_nx)|_{x=0}=\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \sin (b_n x) |_{x=0}$$Thanks for your reading and assistance.

Comment: For question here, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/

Comment: Show that the derivative is done term by term and then $x=0$ gives you the result

Comment: @Conrad,Sorry, I have noticed that, but how to prove that it's derivative is equal to that is done term by term